# Adding Data to Database but get a breakpoint everytime a function is called

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to write myself a Music record database program.
  It works perfectly untill I try using a form to add data using input from textboxes and a button.
It generates a break point and the following error

> An Unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' Occured in
>   System.Data.dll

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
namespace Musicrecord
{
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   -->  using(var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))**
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sql = "INSERT INTO Table(Artist, Album, Release Year) VALUES(@Artist, @Album, @Release year)";
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Album", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Release Year ", textBox3.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I haven't found after several hours of googling a solution.

Comment: Well, the connection string might be wrong. What does tge error message say?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll is all it says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `connectionString` is a local variable, you need to use it as;

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
```

not

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("connectionString"))
```

If you use it as `"connectionString"`, `SqlConnection` *expects* it is a valid connection string. But it is not.

Also, if your column name more than one word, you need to use it with square brackets like `[Release Year]`. It is the same as it's paramter name.

And don't use `AddWithValue`. [It *may* generate unexpected results](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `.Add()` method or it's overloads.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{ 
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table(Artist, Album, [Release Year]) VALUES(@Artist, @Album, @ReleaseYear)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add(@Artist, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(@Album, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(@ReleaseYear, SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
    connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I assumed your all data types are `NVarChar`. Also it is a good practice to specify *size* value as a third parameter in `.Add()` method.